# Is it possible to combine multiple conditions in git's config incudeIf feature?

Tags: git, git-config

```
[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:git@abc.xyz:**/**" && "gitdir:~/some/path/"]
    path = some/config
```

How can I achieve similar behavior using git config? Each of conditions fork fine, but how to combine them using logical "and"? Code snippet above doesn't work as it's syntactically broken git config.

UPD: Technically it's possible by omitting one condition, and create separate file which will include only one `includeIf` with one condition, but it's pretty messy, especially with larger and more complex configurations. I am looking for cleaner solution, logically more similar to what I showed in the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Git, the [`includeIf` directive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes) is designed to include a specified path's configuration based on a single condition. I don't think Git would natively support combining multiple conditions using logical operators like "AND" within a single `includeIf` directive.

The workaround you have mentioned, using nested `includeIf` directives across multiple files, is one method to handle multiple conditions, albeit a bit cumbersome.

A cleaner approach could be to use a script to manage your Git configuration. The script could evaluate multiple conditions, and based on the results, symlink or copy the appropriate configuration file to the desired location.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

REMOTE_URL=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
GIT_DIR=$(pwd)

# Check the conditions
if [[ "$REMOTE_URL" == "git@abc.xyz:**/**" ]] && [[ "$GIT_DIR" == "$HOME/some/path/" ]]; then
    # If both conditions are true, symlink or copy the desired configuration
    ln -sf /path/to/some/config ~/.gitconfig
else
    # Otherwise, symlink or copy a default configuration
    ln -sf /path/to/default/config ~/.gitconfig
fi
```

That script would fetch the current repository's remote URL and working directory path.
It evaluates the conditions using a basic `if` statement. Based on the results, it symlinks the desired configuration file to the `~/.gitconfig` path.

You could run this script manually, or automate its execution using Git hooks or other automation tools. That way, you can manage complex conditional logic outside of Git's native configuration system, and keep your Git configuration files clean and straightforward.

Comment: Yep, thanks. Much cleaner solution. And yes, it probably makes sense that git config won't support features like "AND", because they would also need to support "OR", which makes complexity grow even more.

Comment: Do you think I need to add "bash", "scripting" and answer related tags in my question?

Comment: @zerdox You can add those tags, but it is not mandatory: the main topic remains git config.